# Multiple meta value query using AND/OR approach.

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Good morning all.

I'm kind of racking my brains with this a little as it shouldn't be so difficult.

I have a custom form in my WP backend and it takes meta values chosen by the user to query data and return the results. This is all sent and received via AJAX by the way. I want the user to be able to query by one field, or both. The AND and OR operators aren't working for me as you'll notice. I guess I'm looking for an AND/OR approach.

```
//get the posted values from the search fields  
    $clientname = ($_POST['clientname']);   
    $apartmentname = ($_POST['apartmentname']);
    $date1 = ($_POST['date1']);
    $date2 = ($_POST['date2']); 

//set the dates up properly
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date2);

//get bookings between two dates and by either client name 
    or apartment name or both...
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'bookings',  
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'IN',
                array(
                    'key' => 'clientname',
                    'value' => $clientname,
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'apartmentname',
                    'value' => $apartmentname,
                    'compare' => array('', $apartmentname),
                ),
        ),                              
        'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'after' => $date1,
                    'before' => $date2,
                ),          
        ),
    );
```

Obviously the IN method isn't working and the date query works fine. The whole point is to list all bookings (post type) from a certain client, all bookings in a certain apartment, or, all bookings from a certain client in a certain apartment.

Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where do you use jQuery?

Comment: It would be good to find a method that will allow me to add other fields into the form to query by. I still need to add a Location field into it so the client can query bookings by location.

Comment: Sorry Simon, my jQuery is in another file. But the jQuery works, It gets all the data and sends all the HTML back just fine.

Comment: I mean you point on the problem with PHP/Wordpress, there should be no jQuery in the tags/header of the question then

Comment: Dam, sorry all, that was left over from a previously started question before I figured it out. Am i able to edit it or should I start a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you check the Wordpress documentation you'll notice an error in your code: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Specifically - in the arguments you're using for your query, 'relation' can only have a value of 'AND' / 'OR'. You're currently using 'IN', which I believe is invalid. The relation determines whether the query will need to match all of the arrays below, or just one or more of them. So in your case you'll want to set it to AND if you want to filter by both clientname AND apartmentname, or to OR if you only want to filter by a match with either of them.

So for example you could try something like the following:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'bookings',  
    'meta_query' => array(
    ),                              
    'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => $date1,
                'before' => $date2,
            ),          
    ),
);

if( isset($clientname) && isset($apartmentname) ){ 
   $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
} 

if(isset($clientname)){
     $args['meta_query'][] = array(
         'key' => 'clientname',
         'value' => $clientname,
     );
}

if(isset($apartmentname)){
     $args['meta_query'][] = array(
         'key' => 'apartmentname',
         'value' => $apartmentname,
         'compare' => array('', $apartmentname),
     );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I did try to come up with some conditional statements before but couldnt get the syntax right.
Ill give this a try.

Could you briefly explain what youve done here though so I can understand it please. 

Thanks

Comment: The first block of code sets up your initial $args array. The first if statement adds a relation of 'AND' if you have both $clientname and $apartmentname set - since you only need a relation if you're going to filter by both. The second and third if statements add the relevant queries based on either or both of $clientname and $apartmentname being set.